# Increasing the Idle time of an ASP.Net web page

Tags: asp.net

I have an Asp.Net web application system ,just wanted to know the procedure for increasing the idle time of a webpage

Comment: Do you mean the length of time before IIS recycles an application pool? If not, you might need to expand your question to make our intent a bit clearer =)

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the session timeout value.